# Migrate data from Sql Database to SharePoint list and libraries

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint-2013

Need to migrate data from Sql tables to SharePoint 2013 lists. The database size is approximately 80 GB and need to move the contents from Sql tables to SharePoint lists with same schema.

Just want to know if there is any tool available for this. Or do we need to create an application (probably in .net) to fetch data from Sql and write back to SharePoint lists. 
Any suggestions.

Comment: Do you mean MS SQL Server?

Comment: yes.. MS SQL server.

Answer (score 1):

Try to see this article:

[How to: Create an External Content Type Based on a SQL Server Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee557243.aspx)

In addition, see CodePlex, if you will use SSIS to perform the export[SharePoint List Source and Destination](http://sqlsrvintegrationsrv.codeplex.com/releases/view/17652) in the [Microsoft SQL Server Community Samples: Integration Services](http://sqlsrvintegrationsrv.codeplex.com/) project on CodePlex.

Answer (score 0):

Using current toolchain you may consider using this path:

- Open Excel
- Add a data connection to your SQL Server
- Import all data you want to have as a SharePoint list - you got a sheet now
- Save as *.xlsx file
- Go to SharePoint 365, select "New List"
- Choose "Import from Excel" in the "New" dialog
- There appears a sheet preview where you can adjust column types (most likely needed)
- Click "Next", give the list a name (you may need to remove the silly Guid attached to the generated name, apart from this the name is the table name)
- Click "Create"
- Done

For a single table with roughly 800 records it takes 2 mins approx.